# Attached property not working properly on control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, attached-properties

When I declare a property as normal dependency property then it works however when declared it as attached, it doesn't. I am not sure, what am I missing here. Please help. Following is the code.

**(Set 1 with dependency property works good but Set 2 with attached dependency property doesn't)**

```
<StackPanel Name="PanelControl"  Orientation="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=ControlOrientation, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=LocalConvertor}}"/>
```

**Set 1**

```
FrameworkPropertyMetadata metaData1 = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Vertical, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender);                     
ControlOrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ControlOrientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty), metaData1); 

public Orientation ControlOrientation
{
    get { return (Orientation)(GetValue(ControlOrientationProperty)); }
    set { SetValue(ControlOrientationProperty, value); }
}
```

```
 <clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty Width="742" Height="100" ControlOrientation="Horizontal"/>
```

**Set 2**

```
ControlOrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ControlOrientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty), metaData1); 

public static void SetControlOrientation(UIElement element, Orientation value)
{
    element.SetValue(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientationProperty, value);
}
public static Orientation GetControlOrientation(UIElement element)
{
    return (Orientation)element.GetValue(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientationProperty);
}
```

```
<clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty Width="742" Height="100">
    <Button Content="Test" clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientation="Horizontal"/>
</clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty>
```

Comment: What does it mean "properly"? You can use a property changed callback and handle the property value as you want.

Comment: I mean, case 2 is not updating the orientation of the StackPanel, however when I attached a property changes event to the attached property; I can see the new value coming. Now, this is just a one time binding, and in case 1 as well, the is no event handler for propertychange attached. So why is case 1 working and case 2 not working? I am not able to figure it out!

Comment: The StackPanel has binding to the MainWindow, whereas properties are used on the custom control and on the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the PropertyChanged CallBack to perform an action

```
ControlOrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ControlOrientation", 
                                typeof(Orientation), 
                                typeof(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty), 
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnControlOrentationChnaged)); 

public static void SetControlOrientation(UIElement element, Orientation value)
{
    element.SetValue(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientationProperty, value);
}
public static Orientation GetControlOrientation(UIElement element)
{
    return (Orientation)element.GetValue(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientationProperty);
}

private static void OnControlOrentationChnaged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{       
    // o will be the control on which the property is applied
    //Your logic here
}
```

This might help

Comment: private static void OnControlOrentationChnaged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{          
    o.SetValue(CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientationProperty, (Orientation)e.NewValue);
}

Result is still the same. Also, another question is, why is PropertyChanged call back required here (as in case of attached property) and why is it working fine in case of normal dependency property implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what the problem is but i would presume that it is the binding on your StackPanel? If so then you need to change the `Binding.Path`, if you target an attached property you need parentheses and the owning class, i.e.

```xml
{Binding (clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientation),
         ElementName=...}
```

Comment: Binding is <StackPanel Name="PanelControl"  Orientation="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=ControlOrientation, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=LocalConvertor}}"/> with a resource defined. As I mentioned before, this is working fine when I use the property as a normal dependency property, however it doesn't work when I implement it as an attached property (Complete listing in original post).

Comment: Got My answer. Just learned that, attached properties can not be used as source in data binding.

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: Where did you get the idea that you can't bind to attached properties? I've seen it done.

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: What are you talking about? You just need to modify the path as i showed in my answer, of course you can bind to attached properties, you just need parentheses around them and qualify their location. (In a binding the first input without any prefix (e.g. `ElementName=`, `Path=`) will be the path in case you did not know)

Comment: Here it is, I asked this question @MSDN as well, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b34d28fa-f1e8-48ef-baa3-6f3e6d177ada

Comment: I've uploaded my sample control at SkyDrive @ 

https://skydrive.live.com/#!/?cid=767817aa71b01269&sc=documents&nl=1&uc=1&id=767817AA71B01269%21157... 

which is working fine with normal Dependency property. However, When I change the stack panel binding to as suggested i.e. Orientation="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=(clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientation), Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=LocalConvertor}}" ... and enable the attached property and window code where control is being used, It doesn't work.

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: The person on MSDN obviously has no idea what he/she is talking about, just because that Q/A is hosted on MSDN doesn't mean you get people from Microsoft answering your questions. In your code you always bind to MainWindow but do not seem to set the value on it, i do not quite get what you are even trying to achieve. If you are still convinced that you cannot bind to attached properties then read the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) already.

Comment: @HB no I don't say that since its on MSDN, hence it might be correct. Just that some one asked me where did I get this idea from. Anyways, this is not relevant, and I admit I am just novice on WPF :)... and at the same time, I can't get it work. I am just trying to bind my an attached property nothing else as a part of my learning; and I've tried modifying my code as per my suggestion. May be I missing a point here, hence thought of uploading my code at skydrive! Seek your guidance, Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: I do not understand why you set the property on some other control and then bind to the property on a window instead...

Comment: @HB: I've create a attached property ControlOrientation at Control level and I am just trying to bind that property as source for the Orientation property of the stack panel. What m I binding to the window?

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: No, you bind to the property on the window (using `ElementName=MainWindow`), and you do not appear to set the property there. (By the way, you should not drop the dots in my name, if i did not own this post i would not get notified of your replies)

Answer (score 0):

Since DP's are meant to used only for the control on which you declared it. That's why this is working perfectly working fine with DP-

```
<StackPanel Name="PanelControl"  Orientation="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=ControlOrientation, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=LocalConvertor}}"/>
```

However, when you declare it as an attached property it can be used for any control you want. If you see your output window after loading of this control that binding might be failing since it wasn't able to reslove binding for ControlOrientation. You need to do binding like this -

```
<StackPanel Name="PanelControl"  Orientation="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=(clist:CustomTextBoxUsingDependencyProperty.ControlOrientation), Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=LocalConvertor}}"/>
```

Also for both of your sets, i can see both properties are Register as Attached. Is it typo?

Comment: Yes, that's a type... Sorry about that. This also doesn't work. Please see my last comment, I;ve uploaded my code on skydrive.